# Searching for Arrays containing Vectors of States/Countries

Tags: data-request, geospatial

So I don't really know how I should aks this question to make it understandable for everybody but in specific:

I am searching for Data, which has, for example every point of the path of the Border of the USA (or any other country),

My aim is to make a windows forms control, using an array containing that data and set it to its shape.

Does anyone know where I can get that kind of data? I searched for geodata but i don't know if that is the right search key and everything I got is a .shp File from which I can't do what I want to do, at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .shp files without having to use GIS... Download the shapefile with the resolution (scale) you want from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) then convert it to GeoJSON using [Shape Escape](http://shpescape.com/)... Learn more about GeoJSON at geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

Comment: Okay that's great, now I have my shape file converted to a GeoJSON file. Problem now is that i don't know what to do with that file, it has a lot of arrays and so on, I can't identify them though and i don't know what to do with it. Any further help?

Comment: It depends on your goals, here is a great example using D3: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ and here is one that uses Leaflet: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Answer (score 2):

this repo of world geojson data has the outline of the us
https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries/USA
here's the actual file
https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/USA.geo.json